# Cannot install java on fedora

Tags: java, linux, fedora

I cannot install Java on Fedora.

I looked in the internet for tutorials and followed every of them and still no one of them helped.

If I try to do `java --version~ it says:

```
[root@fedora michael]# java
bash: java: command not found...
Install package 'java-11-openjdk-headless' to provide command 'java'? [N/y] y


 * Waiting in queue... Failed to install packages: java-11-openjdk-headless-1:11.0.11.0.9-2.fc34.x86_64 is already installed
```

I don't know what to do, can someone help?

Comment: Set `JAVA_HOME` in your bash environment.

Comment: Broken java link ? ......... Default Fedora (34) is : `/usr/bin/java` is a link to `/etc/alternatives/java` , which is the selected link to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.11.0.9-2.fc34.x86_64/bin/` ......... https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Java

Comment: And how can i set the JAVA_HOME? or link? idk

Comment: @i_am_a_Programmer_in_Java `export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink $(readlink $(which javac))))) >> /etc/bashrc && . /etc/bashrc`

Comment: Should i do as the dirname the jdk directory? what is readlink? which javac? sorry if i dont understand something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found solution: `alternatives --config java`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

`sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64`

Comment: I did this alredy and it still doesent work

Comment: Which is the output of that command?

Comment: Nothing to do. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the command:

```
dnf list --installed | grep -i java
```

And write what is displayed to you.